# Powershell script to detect Apache server failure and initiate restart

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm a Java programmer, I got an assignment to figure out why Apache server fails/times out since it seems to happen at least 5-10 times a day.

I was Looking through the logs and found these

```
File does not exist: C:/Apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
File does not exist: C:/Apache2/htdocs/browserconfig.xml
File does not exist: C:/Apache2/htdocs/selfupdate
Invalid URI in request GET /../../../../../../../../../../../
Invalid method in request ABCD / HTTP/1.1
Invalid method in request QUALYS / HTTP/1.1
```

Every now and then something new, and everyday it happens. I googled and tried some fixes but something new seems to show up in logs.

I did setup the recovery tab option in properties on first failure, second failure and subsequent failures to be "Restart the service" then checked enable options for stops with errors.

I've decided to write a PowerShell script to check the logs and restart the Apache server when it fails.

```
$services = Get-Service -Name Apache2.2

Get-Service | ? {
  $services -contains $_.Name -and $_.fFailureActionsOnNonCrashFailures
-eq ‘True’
} | Restart-Service
```

Running Get-Service -Name "Apache2.2" | Select-Object -Property *

gave me

```
    Name : Apache2.2 
    RequiredServices : {Afd, Tcpip} 
    CanPauseAndContinue : False 
    CanShutdown : False 
    CanStop : True 
    DisplayName : Apache2.2 
    DependentServices : {} 
    MachineName : . 
    ServiceName : Apache2.2 
    ServicesDependedOn : {Afd, Tcpip} 
    ServiceHandle : 
    Status : Running 
    ServiceType : Win32OwnProcess 
    Site : 
    Container :
```

Please help.

I'm now writing a java program (JAR file) which will launch PowerShell as administrator and run the script to restart Apache. And then set this JAR file to be run every 3 mins via Task Scheduler.

I want to know how to check for failure via PowerShell instead of blindly restarting. Any better solutions/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First I don't know the apache service, but does the service really have the property fFailureActionsOnNonCrashFailures? You can check it with this get-service -name "*Apache*"

Comment: @guiwhatsthat even I'm not sure , I took that fFailureActionsOnNonCrashFailures from microsoft forum SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG. get-service -name Apache2.2 gave me its display name and status.

Comment: Instead of blindly restarting the service find out why it hangs and fix the problem.

Comment: When Get-Service -Name "YOur service" | Select-Object -Property * doesnt show your service_failure... property then is the command which you use not helpfull for you

Comment: @Tomalak I understand, this is a workaround until I figure out the reason for this.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat  Running Get-Service -Name "Apache2.2" | Select-Object -Property *     gave me 

Name                : Apache2.2
RequiredServices    : {Afd, Tcpip}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : True
DisplayName         :    Apache2.2
DependentServices   :   {}
MachineName         :   .
ServiceName         :     Apache2.2
ServicesDependedOn  :   {Afd, Tcpip}
ServiceHandle       :
Status              :      Running
ServiceType         :    Win32OwnProcess
Site                :
Container           :

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Edited my question!

Answer (score 0):

```
What I would do is find the correlating event in the event logs, for when the service stops.  Then right click and create a triggered script or email notification.  The triggered PowerShell script would look like this.

$serviceCheck = Get-Service -Name Apache 2.2 | select status

if ($serviceCheck -eq "Running")
{
    #donothing
}


else
{

  #send email here and restart service

}


Another option would be to run the script as a function and set a sleep timer so it only runs every 5 minutes.  That would look like this:

function Check-Service{

$serviceCheck = Get-Service -Name Apache 2.2 | select status

    if ($serviceCheck.Status -eq "Running")
            {
                          #donothing
            }


    else
            {

                  #send email here and restart service

                 #you can also send an email from here, just make sure you know the smtp server address

            }


        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave. The problem here, I need to check for service failure not status. The service fails but the status remains running. Logs show the above mentioned errors.

Comment: Then set an email notification alert in task scheduler from the event logs that correlate to the failure. That should help.

Comment: "correlate to the failure" how? The current system already sends us notification. Due to Christmas season, we need to reduce the need for manual interference. The service must be restarted automatically to reduce the downtime.